# Is the condensation points in a closed set the largest perfect set contained in it?

Tags: general-topology

We know that the set of all condensation points of a set in Euclidean space is perfect. But could a set contain a larger perfect set than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I just realized that $A$ doesn't have to be closed in the body of the question. In general the set of all condensation points is not contained in the original set, for example $[0, 1]$ is the set of condensation points of $(0, 1)$ so one has to be careful about this. I assume that $A$ is closed below.

Cantor-Brendixon theorem says that any closed subset $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ can be written uniquely (uniqueness is sometimes not mentioned) as $A = P\cup C$ where $P$ is perfect and $C$ is countable while $P\cap C = \emptyset$. Let $A_c$ be the set of condensation points of $A$. Then $A_c$ is perfect and $A\setminus A_c$ is countable. If there was $A_c\subseteq B \subseteq A$ with $B$ perfect, then $A\setminus B$ is countable, so from uniqueness we get $A_c = B$, so in fact $A_c$ is the largest perfect set contained in $A$.

Comment: Could you tell me where I can find a proof of this theorem? For example in books of general topology?

Comment: @Jiu there's a proof in "Descriptive set theory" by Moschivakis, page 50, theorem 2A.1. The proof uses the fact that every non-empty perfect Polish space is uncountable (in fact of size $\mathfrak{c}$), which follows from any two of them being Borel isomorphic.

Comment: But if you show that the Cantor set embeds into any non-empty perfect Polish space, then it should do too. This is showed on page 12, corollary 1A.3.